# Manage gestures priority between two widgets

Tags: flutter

I'm experimenting using the google maps for `flutter` plugin but I'm running into a problem managing the gesture priority.

My map, which need to handle gestures is rendered inside a `PageView` which also listen to some gestures. The thing is, It appears that the gesture handler of `PageView` take the priority over the map one, so if I drag vertically on the map, the map move but if I drag horizontally on the map, the page will switch instead of the map moving.

Is there a way to manage the priority between gesture handlers of widget to fix this sort of problems?

Comment: maybe this could help https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-deep-dive-gestures-c16203b3434f